# How to fix compiler error ': warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast'

Tags: c

My code below gives me a warning:

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast":

```
uint16_t b[4];
uint16_t *g_00;
uint16_t *g_01;
uint16_t *g_10;
uint16_t *g_11;


b[0] = g_00;
b[1] = g_01;
b[2] = g_10;
b[3] = g_11;

printf ("add = %x\n", b[0]);
```

I meant to use `b[0]... b[1]` to save the address of `uint16_t *g_00;`

How can I fix this compiler warning?

Comment: If you want `b` to save an address it will need to be the size of an address.  Not sure why you would not be using a `uint16_t*` for b as well: `uint16_t* b[4]`.

Comment: If he wants to "save the address of `uint16_t *g_00`", it should be `uint16_t **b[4]`; if he wants to save the *value* of `uint16_t *g_00`, it should be `uint16_t *b[4]`.  If you want `b` to save a pointer it will need to be an array of objects with the same *type* as the pointers, not just the same *size* as the pointers; except for `void *`s, C pointers aren't generic addresses, they're pointers to particular types.

Answer (score 2):

> I meant to use b[0]... b[1] to save the **address** of uint16_t *g_00;

To store addresses in `b`'s entries, you need to declare it as array of pointers:

```
uint16_t ** b[4];

uint16_t * g_00;
...

b[0] = &g_00; /* Stores g_00's address. */
```

---

**Update:**

The OP's statement:

```
b[0] = g_00;
```

does **not** store the address of `g_00` but the value carried by `g_00` itself.

If this was the intend (in contrast to storing `g_00`' **address**), the correct declaration of `b` would be:

```
uint16_t * b[4];

uint16_t * g_00;
...

b[0] = g_00; /* Stores g_00's value. */
```

Comment: As "the address of `uint16_t *g_00`" is a pointer to a pointer to a `uint16_t`, presumably you meant `uint16_t **b[4]`.

Comment: *Mathuin*'s edit is plain wrong. However I cannot undo it now and here!

Comment: @guyharris: It wasn't me <tm>!

Comment: Well, I don't know why you couldn't edit your own answer, but it appears that I can, so I just edited it to be correct.  (For anybody who's tempted to remove one of those `*`s, say to yourself "in C, arrays are not pointers" before succumbing to temptation.)

Comment: @guyharris: Thx! I want to rollback not just edit the edit ... and was lost on my micro- mobile's micro display S-)